# How to have a string array which mostly acts as a single string?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, implicit-conversion

in my project I have a class (which may have several derivations) where one field is a string.

We also have code instantiating many objects of this class (separate code for each instance for technical reasons). So the code file may be very long.

For most cases that is ok. But in rare cases I need to have an array of strings as TestValue. I know I could declare it as `string[]`. But since normally we only assign single strings, it would be great to have a possibility to not always have to explicitily creating an array in the code when only a single string is needed, like this:

```
public class Datapoint
{
    public uint Id;

    public string[] TestValue;
}

public void CreateEntries()
{
   Table.Add(new Datapoint { Id = 1, TestValue = "123" });
   Table.Add(new Datapoint { Id = 2, TestValue = "12.9" });
   Table.Add(new Datapoint { Id = 3, TestValue = "Enabled" });
   Table.Add(new Datapoint { Id = 4, TestValue = "Temperature" });
   Table.Add(new Datapoint { Id = 5, TestValue = { "12.3", "9.8", "7.3" } });
}
```

Any Ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Add a second property which is a single string. When you set one of the two properties, clear the other one.

Comment: Already trying to store floating point values into a string is a bad idea

Answer (score 5):

You can create a constructor with the `params` option:

```
public class Datapoint
{
    public uint Id;

    public string[] TestValue;

    public Datapoint(uint id, params string[] testValue)
    {
        Id = id;
        TestValue = testValue;
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
Table.Add(new Datapoint(1, "123"));
Table.Add(new Datapoint(2, "12.9"));
Table.Add(new Datapoint(3, "Enabled"));
Table.Add(new Datapoint(4, "Temperature"));
Table.Add(new Datapoint(5, "12.3", "9.8", "7.3"));
```

Comment: Moving to a constructor also lets you have multiple overloads -- `string` and `string[]` -- if that becomes useful